# plot different metrics in ggplot based on a string vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

This generates a plot:

```
diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = x, color = factor(color))) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(clarity ~ .)
```

[image]

I'd like to do the same for each feature of diamonds x,y,z. Rather than copy paste this function 3 times and change the `y =` within `aes()` I'm trying to write a loop using map:

```
metrics <- diamonds %>% select(x:z) %>% names

# for each metric name string in metrics, want the above plot but witht he y = to be the corresponding metric:
## tried
metrics %>% map(ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = .x, color = factor(color))) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(clarity ~ .))
```

Gives:

> Error: Can't convert a `gg/ggplot` object to function

How can I loop over each item in metrics and generate the above plot for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this can help, you are missing a tilde symbol, plus since **.x** would be string we need to evaluate it as well, I have used get inside, Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem, Thanks :

```
metrics %>% 
  map(~ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = get(.x), color = factor(color))) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(clarity ~ .))
```

Comment: Hm, this does indeed work. What exactly is get() going then? It's converting a string to a sym variable name?

Comment: suppose you have x <- 10, but you are given 'x' as string, how would you extract the value, so get comes to rescue, now there is catch, there is another parameter called envir inside get, which we should be careful about, now in this case it might not be a great issue but I couldn't come up with something better for now. Read about Non Standard Evaluation, I think you will like it a lot